# accesing individual values of k means clustering in r

Tags: r

```
mydata<- read.csv("q.csv")
# K-Means Cluster Analysis
fit <- kmeans(mydata, 3) # 3 cluster solution
# get cluster means
abc<-aggregate(mydata,by=list(fit$cluster),FUN=mean)
abc[1]
# append cluster assignment
mydata <- data.frame(mydata, fit$cluster) 
mydata
```

how do i access individual values of the k means result?
Im able to access only the single vector using abc[1]

Comment: If would be helpful if you included sample data in your question to make your problem [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). For the sample data, be clear on exactly what value you are trying to extract.

Comment: Try `str(fit)` to take a look at what this object contains.

Comment: q.csv contains three columns of data consisting of 200 entries

Answer (score 1):

In case `nrow(mydata) == length(fit$cluster)`, I would try to use cbind function.
Otherwise you won't be able to do it.

Comment: can rows be extracted as an array?

Comment: I would say you can extract it natively as a vector. 
In case you want to create an array, best way would be by casting data like: `array(fit$cluster)`, although there are other structures more friendly and efficient, such as data.frame, matrix... that I strongly recommend.